# Placing enemies at random points

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been worried about the problem for a long time, so that every time I run, my enemies randomly place me on points. I use DUPLICATE on objects. For example, points form balls, if I have more enemies, they do not want to display correctly on road points. My goal is to make objects appear correctly and randomly on points at startup.
Thank you for advice

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random; 

public class Randomplace : MonoBehaviour {


    public int minNumber =0;
    public GameObject[] wayPoints;
    public GameObject[] enemys;  
    Vector3 pos;
    private List<int> _validNumbers;
    private int number;

 private void Awake()
    {
        _validNumbers = new List<int>();
        for (int i = minNumber; i <=  wayPoints.Length; i++)
            _validNumbers.Add(i);   
   }
         
       
  void   Start()
    {    
    

 for (int j=0; j<enemys.Length;j++) {
       if(enemys[j].activeInHierarchy)    {  
          
           enemys[j].SetActive(true);
           number = GetRandomNumber();
           GameObject waypoint = wayPoints[number];
          Vector3 pos= waypoint.transform.position;
           enemys[j].transform.position =  pos; //places objects at random points 
         }
         }
         }
     
    private void Update()
    {          

    }

    private int GetRandomNumber()
    {
        var nextIndex = Random.Range(0, _validNumbers.Count - 1); //
         var result    = _validNumbers[nextIndex];
        _validNumbers.RemoveAt(nextIndex);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what exactly the issue/question is here tbh

Comment: so that, for example, 4 enemies randomly change position on wayPoints. Sorry for bad English, I don't know English.